# Set functions satisfying if $f(X) \le f(Y)$ and $Z \cap (X \cup Y) = \emptyset$, then $f(X \cup Z) \le f(Y \cup Z)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, terminology, computer-science

I am investigating set functions $f : 2^\Omega \to \mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following two properties:

1. (monotone) For all $X, Y \subset \Omega$, if $X \subseteq Y$, then $f(X) \le f(Y)$.
2. (property name unknown) For all $X, Y, Z \subset \Omega$, if $f(X) \le f(Y)$ and $Z \cap (X \cup Y) = \emptyset$, then $f(X \cup Z) \le f(Y \cup Z)$.

For an example of such a function, consider any $g : \Omega \to \mathbb{N}$ and set $f(X) = \sum_{x \in X} g(x)$.

For an example of a monotone function that does not satisfy (2), let $G = (\Omega, E)$ be a graph and denote $G[X]$ the induced subgraph by $X \subseteq \Omega$. Let $f(X)$ be the length of the longest path in $G[X]$. It is obviously monotone, but does not satisfy (2) because when $f(X)$ is just slightly less $f(Y)$, a new vertex $z$ may connect two large connected components of $G[X]$ while having no neighbors in $G[Y]$.

Does property (2) have a common name in the literature? What is known about such functions? For me, these kinds of functions arise in computer science, specifically dynamic programming algorithms, though I imagine that they may be of independent combinatorial interest.

Comment: @bof Yes, my bad, thanks for the correction!

Comment: It might be more interesting to consider not the function $f$ itself, but the total preorder it induces, seeing as you only compare values of $f$.